# service tomcat status

Tags: tomcat

how do you implement tomcat status?
I did

```
status(){
    ps -aef| grep tomcat |grep -v grep
}
```

it shows 2  more proccesses other than the valid tomcat process.  is there a better way?

```
service tomcat status
root      4107     1  1 19:11 ?        00:00:47 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root      4620  4376  0 20:11 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh /sbin/service tomcat status
root      4625  4620  0 20:11 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/tomcat status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following in my init script. **It's not perfect!** But it does get the job done in the case of a single Tomcat on a box:

```
isRunning() {
numproc=`ps -ef | grep "java" | grep "catalina" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`

if [ ${numproc} -gt 0 ]; then
    return 1
fi

return 0
}
```

Comment: This works ok, I suppose I might just grep for something like "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start" instead of grepping for java and then following that up with a grep for catalina.  Also I usually try to avoid multiple return statements.  I would save off the bool to a return var, and then return that just once.

Answer (score 1):

On startup - you can set an environment variable called CATALINA_PID which should be the name of a file. The tomcat startup scripts will notice that variable and create a file with the pid. Then you can use that to key in on whether tomcat is alive.

```
status(){
    ps -fp `cat $CATALINA_PID`
}
```

ps will also exit 0 if the process exists. 1 if it does not which should also be and easier safer.

Comment: Is the extra "ps" redundant?

Comment: doh - I fixed the copy - tx